# How can we use promise under readline.on function on (Node.js 8. Currently)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Not able to use await/async under readline.on function i don't know why it is not waiting untill results to return ? also used promise under await function but no use when i return promise also no use. Can any one who expert in node js,Es6 Please help me, This is my humble request to all developers. Can any one please help me to solve this issue and Thanks in advance.

```
var readline = require('readline');
fs = require('fs');
redis = require('redis');

var redisClient = redis.createClient();

var filePath = './sample-data/whoodle_index_file_0.psv';

async function getSampleData() {
    let rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    rl.on('line', async (line) => {

        let obj = {};
        let data = line.split('|');
        obj['name'] = data[0];

        console.log('first line of execution process');

        let result = await getDataFromRedisUsingKey(obj['name']);
        console.log('result' + result);
        console.log('secound line of execution process');
        console.log('want to use this results in to some other functions');

        let obj2 = {};
        obj2['name'] = data[3];

        console.log('third line of execution process');

        let result2 = await getDataFromRedisUsingKey(obj2['name']);
        console.log('result' + result);
        console.log('fourth line of execution process');
        console.log('want to use this results in to some other functions');

    });

}

getSampleData();

async function getDataFromRedisUsingKey(name) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        redisClient.get(name, function (err, result) {
            console.log("result----------------------" + result);
            if (err) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

Showing result like this on console 

first line of execution process
first line of execution process
result----------------------null
result----------------------null
resultnull
secound line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
third line of execution process
resultnull
secound line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
third line of execution process
result----------------------null
result----------------------null
result2null
fourth line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
result2null
fourth line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions

But im expecting like this

first line of execution process
result----------------------null
resultnull
secound line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
third line of execution process
result----------------------null
result2null
fourth line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
first line of execution process
result----------------------null
resultnull
secound line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
third line of execution process
result----------------------null
result2null
fourth line of execution process
want to use this results in to some other functions
```

Comment: You forgot to `await` the `Promise`. You should also `reject` on errors, not `resolve`

Comment: If i create a function with some name and paste it that new promise code and calling that function using await also same no use i mean that await function is not executing first

Comment: Please post that code if you want debugging help.

Comment: Just now updated question, Please check once again

Comment: You should "return" the promise

Comment: if i return promise also no use, Please check question once again i have written Expected output and also present what im getting result on console.

Comment: Please can any one help me to resolve this issue its a very small but i'm stuck on it at await/async under readline.on function i don't know why it is not waiting untill results to return ? Can any one who expert in node js,Es6 Please help me, This is my humble request to all Please.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the mess is caused by mixing callback and Promise code: each async callback starts executing in the order of `'line'` event till the first `await` and then the order is unpredictable, based on the other async Promise resolving. If you can use Node.js 11, try to rewrite your code using async iterators API. See examples [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator) and [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this issue using node js 11  ?

Comment: I've tried in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a mock-up for the expected behavior, using an array of promises as a "waiting condition":

```
// mock-up rl
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const rl = new EventEmitter();

// mock-up the getDataFromRedis thing: this gives a Promise that is fulfilled after 1s
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

// "waiting condition" variable
const lockers = [];

rl.on('line', () => {
  // wrap the code in a Promise that we add as a waiting condition
  lockers.push(new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // now we wait for all previously registered conditions to be OK before going on
    await Promise.all(lockers);
    // now we do the code with Redis
    console.log('x1');
    const r1 = await doSomething();
    console.log('x2');
    const r2 = await doSomething();
    // finally we resolve the current Promise to release lock on following processes
    resolve();
  }));
});

// start the process: mock-up rl's behavior: fire several events in a row
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rl.emit('line');
}
```

However, this architecture is really weird: why do you need to "sequentialize" the process? I mean: even if everything goes parallel, you can still retrieve ordered data in the end, assuming you code the thing for it!

To explain what happens under the hood:

- `rl` fires `"line"`
- JS summons the listener to that event, and as a good single-threaded event-based language, it executes the listener's code until it reaches the first `await`, then it checks if another piece of code requested processing
- in the mean time, `rl` fired another (or some other) `"line"` event, so that's "another piece of code that requests processing", therefore JS executes it, until it reaches an `await` or the like
- again, on `await` it'll go check its queue of events to process, and now you guess what happens if `rl` fires events faster than your inner code's first `await`: all of `rl`'s events will be first in line for interpreter time, and all your inner code will have to wait before being ready to process their last bits of code

However, when JS starts again processing your inner code (i.e. after Redis' async function resolved and after any previously registered event has been processed), it loads it with its scope, so you don't have to worry about mixing your data. The only worrying point is retrieving the order of that data: if needed, then you have to explicitly consider it, for instance using an array of promises (as the Promise objects in the array obviously stay in order, no matter the execution order of these Promises).

Comment: Note that `lockers.push(...)` is executed _after_ `await Promise.all(lockers)`, despite what my in-code comments might imply: it's not "now we wait", it's more like "here we wait". It's the classical precedence of operators (parentheses here) in a synchronous, line-by-line bit of code. ;)

Comment: Actually we have tons of data that we needs to use it in async to check whether if same data exists then we need to skip that line so thats why im checking for each line using  promise on database ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your constraints here, but you can probably "skip" data at the end, or distinctify duplicates using the DB language. But once again: I don't know your environment/requirements!

Comment: Is "async" required in the line "rl.on('line', async () => {"?

Comment: Indeed @MikeShiyan the only `async` that we need here is the one on the promise executor: `async (resolve, reject) => ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy from a comment above: If I understand it correctly, the mess is caused by mixing callback and Promise code: each async callback starts executing in the order of `'line'` event till the first `await` and then the order is unpredictable, based on the other async Promise resolving. If you can use Node.js 11, try to rewrite your code using async iterators API. See examples [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator) and [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).

I've tried to rewrite (fixing some typos like `result2` instead of `result` in the last output block). Does this code work?

```js
'use strict';

const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const redis = require('redis');

const redisClient = redis.createClient();

const filePath = './sample-data/whoodle_index_file_0.psv';

async function getSampleData() {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        const obj = {};
        const data = line.split('|');
        obj['name'] = data[0];

        console.log('first line of execution process');

        const result = await getDataFromRedisUsingKey(obj['name']);
        console.log('result ' + result);
        console.log('secound line of execution process');
        console.log('want to use this results in to some other functions');

        const obj2 = {};
        obj2['name'] = data[3];

        console.log('third line of execution process');

        const result2 = await getDataFromRedisUsingKey(obj2['name']);
        console.log('result2 ' + result2);
        console.log('fourth line of execution process');
        console.log('want to use this results in to some other functions');
    }
}

getSampleData();

function getDataFromRedisUsingKey(name) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        redisClient.get(name, function (err, result) {
            console.log('result----------------------' + result);
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using node 8.9 its giving error on 8.9 for await (const line of rl) {
        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word, So it will work on node 11.4 only ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems so, only starting from Node.js 11.4.

Comment: Yes i want this output only but it is working on 11.4v only but unfortunately im using 8.9 ?

Comment: Also its giving an warning like this (node:24105) ExperimentalWarning: Readable[Symbol.asyncIterator] is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time. So it may change at any time this feature ?

Comment: I doubt it will change significantly, but yes, it may. Maybe someone else will suggest some Node.js 8 compatible solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @vsemozhetbyt you tried a lot, Once again thank you so much. If you know 8v compatible solution please post answer for me,Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to unmark this as answer and add a note in the question that you need a way for Node.js 8. Currently, I cannot think of any(